# Classname Search in Nexus 3

Tags: nexus3

The "Classname Search" seems to be not available in Nexus 3 and will not according to https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-6811, isn't it?
So I tried to search for a classname with [maven-indexer](https://github.com/apache/maven-indexer) and my local Nexus 3. However, it does not return a match. Does the Nexus 3 index by default contain any information about the classnames?
I was thinking about implementing classname search plugin/bundle for Nexus 3 but am not sure if the necessary data can be fetched in current Nexus 3 (3.3.1-01), can it?

Answer (score 4):

There is no support for class name search in Nexus 3.

Comment: I am still hoping for the Nexus 3.x that includes all the important Nexus 2.x features, as REST interfaces, classname search, xml snippets, staging...

Comment: Personally I do not think that all of those are going to be available any time soon. Some are definitely on the way though. It depends on customer demand.

Answer (score 4):

For those who come after me, stumble upon this question and can't believe a feature like classname search could be pulled from a repo manager...

According to the comment on Sonatype's Jira (https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-13133?focusedCommentId=470279&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-470279) classname search is not going to be implemented for Nexus 3. Bad news.

> We're aware that this is painful for those of who you used this regularly. There were a fair number of scalability and support problems related to this feature which show up at large scales, which is why we haven't ported this over yet. (As you can probably imagine, there are a fair number of classes to index in a few terabytes of .jar files.)

There is a community driven feature comparison chart here: https://binary-repositories-comparison.github.io/

To be honest, I was quite shocked when I saw how many features Nexus 3 is missing compared to version 2 (or basically all of the other repo managers).

A lot of my customers want to get on Nexus 3 to have support for NPM or Docker proxying. So if you're looking for an alternative to Nexus, I'd recommend Artifactory.

Comment: How come it's possible at https://search.maven.org/ but "a few terabytes of .jar files" is an issue for Nexus -.-